# Angular Unit Testing: Observable not returning results

Tags: angular, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm working on an old Angular app and trying to unit test that the functions work as expected.

I'm simply trying to test that a function returns the correct http request but the test isn't able to read the observable.

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUrl() {
     //lots of logic to determine which url to get

     return this.http.put(url, null, { headers: requestHeaders, withCredentials: true 
     }).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        return response;
     }));
  }

}
```

Is there a way to test the result of this getUrl function?

If I simply log the result of this function, I get an observable.

```
Observable{_isScalar: false, source: Observable{_isScalar: false, source: Observable{_isScalar: ..., source: ..., operator: ...}, operator: MapOperator{project: ..., thisArg: ...}}, operator: CatchOperator{selector: handleError(error) { ... }, caught: Observable{_isScalar: ..., source: ..., operator: ...}}}
```

And If I subscribe to this observable, nothing happens.

```
let test = null;
service.getUrl().subscribe((value) => {
  test = value
});

console.log('test result', test);
```

This will log null.

Would appreciate any advice on how I can get the result of this function. thanks

Comment: Put `console.log(test)` inside the `service.getUrl().subsribe()` to print the returned response.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seem to print anything. It's as if the subscribe function doesn't actually do anything. It works in the actual code, but does nothing in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to unit testing services in Angular.
You can read about it here: [Testing HTTP Services](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-http-services)

Another approach is to create a mock service in your `*.spec.ts` file.

```
const MOCK_GET_URL_RESPONSE = 'test';

export class MockService() {
    // Implement service functions here
    getUrl(): Observable<any> {
        return of(MOCK_GET_URL_RESPONSE);
    }
}

describe('ABCComponent', () => {
    let component: ABCComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ABCComponent>;
    let service: MockService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ABCComponent],
            imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            // Provide your service and indicate which
            // class is to be used to mock it
            providers: [{ provide: MyService, useClass: MockService }],
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        service.getUrl().subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(res); // test
            expect(res).not.toBeNull(); // true
        });
    });
});
```

If you choose to test using mock services and in general, it is best practice to define the data type of response. So map your API responses to a type instead of `any`.

Comment: Great, thanks for that explanation - super helpful! makes a whole lot of sense to mock the service than to try call the real one with mock data.

Comment: Great! If the answer helped you, please upvote and mark as best answer. Thanks!